# database record is not deleted permanently from SQLite database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am develop android app which can be stored data in `sqlite` database.in my app I deleted record from database base on primary key then my record is not deleted from database . this deleted record is stored on database who's primary key is `null` and other filed have some other values.

Then how can I delete my record permanently from database in android.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must not let your code insert a null on your database. You must handle or validate it before inserting on a database. Try to use the other `columns` to your `where` clause.

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE other_column='value'
```

dataBase.execSQL("delete from "+ mytable+" where PrimeryID='"+PrimeryID+"'");

Then I suggest to add a layer that will validate all the insertion for `nulls`.